# Stack of Cards Shuffle By Swiping In Flutter

Tags: flutter, carousel, flutter-animation, flutter-card, flutter-stacked

How to make a card stack component that you can swipe through and has the cards move to the front or the back depending on which direction you are swiping from!

Refer:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9KCxdkb4h0&ab_channel=DarrenNorthcott-Figma%2CUX%26UI

Comment: Try these: https://pub.dev/packages/swipeable_card_stack, https://pub.dev/packages/card_swiper, https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_card_swiper, https://pub.dev/packages/tcard

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [swipe_deck](https://pub.dev/packages/swipe_deck) package. I think this package is fulfill your requirements.